# Clarity on issue with nested functions and environments in R

Tags: r, function, environment

I created a function to save data to a specific location which is loaded as part of a package when launching rstudio:

```
save_data <- function(fileName, file_name){

    file_path <- paste0("~/", file_name)
    save(list=deparse(substitute(fileName)), file=file_path)
}
```

but when calling this function from inside another function it returns an "Error saving the following file: ...".

To reproduce the issue I created a savetestfunction:

```
savetest <- function(fileName){

    data1 <- fileName * 10
    save_data(data1, file_name = "test.RData")

    data1
}
```

and a small savetestscript:

```
source("savetestfunction.R")

x <- c(1:10)

data1 <- savetest(x)
```

I spent a long time assuming the issue stemmed from the environments and what was being seen from each (e.g. save_data function loaded on startup couldn't see the temporary environment created when calling the savetestfunction) but as a test I tried adding a `print(fileName)` to the save_data function and to my surprise it could in fact see what fileName was at this point.

The Fix: I updated the function so that it assigned fileName within the environment created by the save_data function and it now functions as intended...

```
save_data <- function(fileName, file_name){

    file_path <- paste0("//placeholder//", file_name)

    assign(deparse(substitute(fileName)), fileName)

    save(list=deparse(substitute(fileName)), file=file_path)
}
```

The Confusion: This then led me to believe that fileName was perhaps a promise when it was being saved however save() contains an argument eval.promises which is True by default so it can't be this!

The Question: What was causing this issue? (Confusion related to environments? Promises?) What could have been done to avoid this?

Edit: Tried to use saveRDS but didn't have success with this. More interested in why the save doesn't work in the first place rather than an actual fix as the assign within the save_data function already lets it function.

Comment: I don't think I got what you are trying to achieve. First of all, change the argument names: `fileName` and `file_name` are incredibly confusing. What is `fileName` in `save_data` supposed to be? An object? A character vector with names of the objects you want to save?

Comment: I cannot reproduce *any* error. But I made 2 changes: 1) `file_path <- paste0("~/", file_name)` in the first function and the filename to `file_name = "test.RData"` in the second function.

Comment: @nicola Sorry i can see how the argument names are confusing. fileName is the object (most often a data frame but could be a list for example) that you wish to save. file_name is the name you would like to save the file as.

Comment: @Rui Barradas I have updated the post with the changes you made as I think it makes the question clearer.

Comment: If `fileName` is a standard R object, I strongly suggest to use `saveRDS` (and its counterpart `readRDS`) instead of `save`. In that way, you don't need to know the name of the object and you don't incur in errors when calling inside inner functions.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think the error will only occur if the save_data function is loaded on startup. In my case, the save_data function is in a project called r-lib that is loaded on startup with my .rprofile `load_all("~/r-lib")`

Comment: @Tino the deparse(substitute()) is used to save the object with the same name that was passed to save_data as fileName. In the example above the save_data function will save the object data1 with the name data1 and not as fileName.